# Integrating OSMDroid with Fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, osmdroid

So I managed to get a better understanding how OSMDRoid works... by extending Activity.

```
public class POfflineMapView extends Activity implements LocationListener, MapViewConstants{

    private MapView myOpenMapView;
    private OsmMapsItemizedOverlay mItemizedOverlay;
    private ResourceProxy mResourceProxy;
    private OverlayItem overlayItem;
    private ArrayList<OverlayItem> mItems = new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        mResourceProxy = new DefaultResourceProxyImpl(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.offline_map_activity);
        myOpenMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
        myOpenMapView.getTileProvider().clearTileCache();

        //.... code continues
    }
}
```

However, I am having difficulty finding examples to display using OSMDRoid Maptiles using Fragments implementation (for example, SherlockMapFragment). Does anyone know how to implement this, or is able to provide a sample implementation guide for me to follow on?

I need to do this as I have an Activity container, and when I click on a certain button, I want to do a fragment .replace() to replace the container with the OSMDRoid maps fragment instead, in possible.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The osmdroid map view works the same whether you use it inside of an Activity or Fragment. Just place it in your layout file and inflate it in your Fragment or create the MapView directly in the `onCreateView` method of your Fragment.

To create a fragment containing the default map you could do something like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  return new MapView(getActivity(), 256);
}
```

in your fragment class.

If you like to use a layout which contains your MapView you can do something like this in your fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.offline_map_activity, null);
  myOpenMapView = v.findViewById(R.id.openmapview);
  return v;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately for me it is not as easy as what you have shown... if you can see my codes "setContentView(R.layout.offline_map_activity);
        myOpenMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.openmapview);" I need to do this instead. How do i do it in fragments?

Comment: I have problem using a single instance of the MapView() when I rotate the device. The map is initially created and after rotation, I only see the grids as if the map was not initialized.

Answer (score 1):

Create *onCreateView* method in Fragment like this (change RelativeLayout to your layout type):

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(offline_map_activity, container, false);
    myOpenMapView = (MapView) rl.findViewById(R.id.openmapview);

    //.... code continues

    return rl;
}
```